# What precedent is there in an adventure for luring a party with will-o'-wisps?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, gm-techniques

We are looking to use will-o'-wisps in a Feywild adventure but face a challenge. Since the earliest editions of DnD to the latest, will-o'-wisps have been described as creatures that "lure other creatures toward dismal fates and feed on their misery."

Yet, whenever adventuring parties I have been in have seen floating orbs, the party became cautious because of the risk of wisps.

What DMs have *ever* been successful luring a party by the light of a will'o-wisp.  The creature seems high in concept yet challenging to play in execution.

If a DM has ever successfully lured a party with a will'o-wisp in a published adventure or one of their own design - how was the scenario designed to lure them?

Comment: The question is specifically about experience at the table and has an answer based on experience at the table. Care to explain the close votes?

Comment: @MarkWells I did not vote, however I can see how one might have a problem with the phrasing "Yet, has any party" and "Has any DM ever successfully...". It would be impossible to answer 'no' to this question, because you'd need to know every dnd game ever played. So the question may not be answerable.

Comment: I have added the gm techniques tag to this question - I think it fits into that class of question. You have more or less asked "how does one, as a gm runining an adventure, present a successful Will o wisp encounter or scenario? "

Comment: Not enough to warrant an answer unto itself, but Curse of Strahd has a Will-o-Wisp random encounter in Ch.2.

Answer (score 10):

I was, and the rest of my party, recently lured in by a Will-o'-Wisp in the DOTMM module. However our DM did not describe it as a light, rather it was described as a person shouting out for help, wailing and screaming.

Initially we were obviously suspicious, but decided to follow it anyways. I think the trick here is to not make it obvious that it is a will-o'-wisp, especially if you are playing with a group that has played dnd for a long time.

We all pretty much knew we were walking into a trap and as a result were on high alert. However when we reached a large cave opening what we found was a bunch of large undead, and we completely forgot about the cries for help that initially brought us there.

My character ended up going down towards the end of the fight, and that is when the will-o'-wisp reappeared and used *Consume Life* on my character. *(Don't worry, I survived)*

**I think the key thing about the will-o'-wisp is that it doesn't need to just be a ball of light. It can also work in tandem with larger enemies in order to consume life as creatures are killed by the larger foes.**

It all depends really on how experienced your group is, how suspicious they are, and how likely they are to help someone even if it could possibly be a trap.

Another example could be to give your party a friendly fey creature of light (actually will-o-wisp) that helps guide them through a swamp. Instead it lures them into a trolls lair and feasts on them once they go down.

Comment: Traditionally will-o'-wisps lure people away just by their light. D&D players might be a bit wary for that, but you could certainly use it in an ambush where you expect to see the lights of a distant town or city

Answer (score 10):

### High Rollers' Lightfall campaign features a memorable will-o'-wisp encounter

High Rollers is the Yogscast D&D stream. Their first campaign, Lightfall, featured an encounter with a will-o'-wisp in episode 3. You can read the episode summary [here](https://yogscast.fandom.com/wiki/HighRollers:_Lightfall/Episode_3) (it also includes a link to the video). The nice thing about this example is that you can watch the video to see exactly how it played out at the table. However, I'll summarize the encounter and try to give some analysis of what made it effective.

The party was investigating a series of murders, and one of the clues they had was a rumor about a "local legend of the cursed boy who experimented on his family before they died and he killed himself". This rumor led them to an abandoned farmstead, where they encountered the will-o'-wisp, which simply appeared as a glowing, floating orb. The wisp did not act aggressively, but instead receded into the farmstead. The party followed, thinking it might be the spirit of the cursed boy. By strategically appearing in certain areas and then disappearing, the wisp manipulated the party into splitting up, with one left alone upstairs while the others explored the basement. Finally, at this point, the wisp turned aggressive and ambushed the lone party member, and a battle ensued. With a 3 floor arena (basement, ground floor, upper floor), the wisp's ability to float right through floors and ceilings made it extra difficult to pin down, and the party ended up retreating.

A couple of factors contributed to the effectiveness of this will-o'-wisp trap. First, the farmstead wasn't *just* a hideout for a will-o'-wisp. The local legend of the cursed boy provided a plausible explanation for the floating light, so the players didn't immediately assume the encounter would lead to combat. Once, two of the party members had been led into the basement. There were some items there that captured their attention serving as a distraction to keep them there longer while the wisp ambushed the 3rd party member. In addition, the party came to the farmstead to search for clues in a murder case -- again, they were primed to expect investigation, not combat. This, in turn, made them worry less about splitting up to search more of the house, and it made them willing to enter despite not being fully rested after previous encounters. All of this meant that the players did not attack the wisp on sight, but instead treated the encounter as an investigation, which allowed the wisp to lure them into the perfect place to spring its trap.

Interestingly, the setup around this encounter meant that the DM didn't even need to resort to trickery such as making the will-o'-wisp appear like a person shouting, and the wisp also didn't need help from other monsters to soften up the players. In fact, putting other monsters in might have ruined the ambush by tipping off the players that this was going to be a combat encounter. Just appearing by itself as a silent ball of light was enough to get the players into a situation where they ended up having to retreat.

Comment: Great example. Setting expectation of a ghost and an investigation of a murder clearly made a huge difference in the party feeling safe enough to split up.

Comment: @Praxiteles I think the common thread for effective wisp encounters is that they don't present as obvious combat encounters, but rather as a mysteries to be solved, so as to prey on the natural curiosity of the average PC.

Answer (score 5):

I ran an encounter with them a few months ago. The party was traveling through a swamp, trying to visit the castle of a vampire. They were invited there, but still very suspicious of the intentions of said vampire (who was the mother of one of the party members).

When they went through the swamp, the path was lighted by a set of small glowing orbs, and as the party approached one, that one would dim out and a new one would appear a little further down the path. Since the Wisps are very stealthy and they could never approach a light, and they never moved, they were a little suspicious but couldn't really find anything strange going on.

The initial path they showed also appeared pretty easy to travel compared to the rest of the swamp, so they became a bit less worried after a good 15 minutes of just following the trail of lights. Obviously, they did not realize that there were only 4 lights, and the one winking out would quickly travel back to the front of the column.

At least not until they suddenly found themselves in the middle of a bog and ambushed by a pack of Dire Wolves. (Granted, I don't know to what extent they realized something was up, but they couldn't find an in-character justification to do anything other than follow the useful, lighted path.)

Comment: Ha - brilliant! One could imagine variations where if the first few lights were actually *real* (not wisps - but resembled wisps) and then the wisps took over later in the trail - it could make it even more difficult for the party to detect.